# Pass parameter from Ajax to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I call a PHP file from AJAX and I want to pass also a variable. This is my code:

```
echo "<h4 style='color:white'>Messages</h4>";
echo "<textarea cols='50' rows='10' style='font-size: 24px;'></textarea><br><br>";
echo "<button id='sendmessage' style='padding:10px'>Submit</button>";
echo "<button id='deletemessage' style='margin-left:5px;padding:10px'>Delete</button>";


echo "<script>
    jQuery('#sendmessage').click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            data: { content: jQuery('textarea').val() },
            url:'wp-content/themes/dt-chocolate/postmessages.php',
            success:function(data){}
        });
    });
    </script>"
```

and the PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain/wp-config.php');

$post = array(
        'post_content'   =>  data.content,
        'post_title'     =>  "testing",
        'post_status'    =>  'publish',
        'post_type'      =>  'post',
        'post_category'  =>  array(28)  // Default empty.
    );  



wp_insert_post( $post );
?>
```

However, the content of the post is "datacontent" and not the actual text from the textarea. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "<script>
jQuery('#sendmessage').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: { content: jQuery('textarea').val() },
        url:'wp-content/themes/dt-chocolate/postmessages.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data){}
    });
});
</script>";
```

-

```
$post = array(
    'post_content'   =>  $_POST['content'],
    'post_title'     =>  "testing",
    'post_status'    =>  'publish',
    'post_type'      =>  'post',
    'post_category'  =>  array(28)  // Default empty.
);
```

Set `.ajax` `type` (method) to `'POST'`, then you can read POST request variables in PHP from the `$_POST` array.

Comment: That's work. I don't know php and I tried to do it with everything I found in Google. Thank you again. I will check your answer as the best in 7 minutes due to SE limit.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'd probably want to use POST instead of GET. Just add type: 'POST' to the ajax params or use the "post()" function.

On the server side, the way the value should be retrieved is by using the $_GET (or $_POST) global variables. Your content should be in $_GET['content'].